# What is an Augmented Vector Space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-cone

I am studying a little bit of Convex Analysis, especially the structure of the closed convex sets (in French). I came across a term that kind of confused me which is "espace vectoriel augmenté" or "augmented vector space". It is defined as following:

> Let $E$ be a vector space with a finite demension. Let $\hat{E}=E\oplus\mathbb{R}$ be the augmented vector space.

What does the name even mean? Is it like augmenting the demension of $E$?
Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: It is adding one dimension to the space, so elements of $E \oplus \mathbb{R}$ are pairs $(v,\alpha)$ where $v \in E$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. I think the idea in cases you're looking at is that if $X \subseteq E$ is a convex set, and $F$ is another vector space, we can extend affine functions $X \rightarrow F$ to affine functions $E \rightarrow F$, but they will only be affine, not linear (they won't preserve $0$ in general). There is a unique extension to a linear map (affine and preserving $0$) $E \oplus \mathbb{R} \rightarrow F$, by using the extra dimension to "take up the slack".